# Google Scripts - Automatically updating the text validation for a google form from data in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to automate the resetting (update) a google form text validation from data that's been placed in a cell on a google sheet. The hope is that I can update the google sheet and then run this script to automatically update the form's validation.

This is the code i've tried to set on my own but i am getting an error message stating that the method can not be found for the setValidation.

```
function updateFormFromData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var question = ss.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var options = ss.getRange(3,1).getValue();

var form = FormApp.openById('1g4L7F0TUj9hVIBNbHg8gdTect_qyEBYGle-z2gnpO7A');
var allItems = form.getItems();
var formQ1 = allItems[0].asTextItem();
var textVal = 
FormApp.createTextValidation().requireTextContainsPattern(options).build();
formQ1.setTitle(question).setValidation(options);  
}
```

Comment: You need to set the builded TextValidation (`textVal`) as the argument for the method `setValidation()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
formQ1.setTitle(question).setValidation(options);
```

You're passing `options` to `setValidation` when you should be passing `textVal`, which is the validation item you created using `options`.

Like this:

```
formQ1.setTitle(question).setValidation(textVal)
```